# Using ResultSetMapping in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a query like this:

```
  $query = "select run_record_detail.id from
            (select max(id) as run_record_id from run_record  where delete_flag=0 group    by test_run_id) rr
               inner join 
            run_record_detail
            on rr.run_record_id = rr.run_record_id
            where delete_flag=0 and test_case_id IN (:ids)";

    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('\Test\Entity\RunRecordDetail', 'run_record_detail');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('run_record_detail', 'id', 'id');
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($query, $rsm);
    $query->setParameter('ids', $testCaseIdArray);
    $result = $query->getResult();
```

I am trying to use ResultsetMapping to bind run_record_detail to RunRecordDetail object. I want RunRecordDetail object in the output. But I am getting only its id(as I have selected ). Please help me getting this object.
I am following Doctrine doc http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html